# What constriants do I need to fix in order to make this iphone app fit the 4-inch screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

Please be very clear with your instructions as I have little experience with working with xcode and making apps in it. Here I am simply trying to make a old iphone app fit the 4-inch screen. I have already made all views into an autolayout and the view you can barely see already works. However, the UIImageView (as you can see below) does not scale to the entire screen like I would like. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to toggle the simulated metrics between 4" and 3.5" to see how the view is rendered for both?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it appears to work. As you can see in the background, the UIImageView is set in 4-inch retina mode however it is showing the distorted obama photo when the project is actually run.

Comment: Here is a good guide on updating to the 4 inch screen. It addresses the same stretching/compressing issues you are having.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display

Comment: I admit that it is a very good guide, but I am editing a project that has a .xib file. Your tutorial has instructions for a storyboard which is only the most recent version of Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting your auto-sizing masks so they re-size correctly?

Comment: do you know of a tutorial that teaches you how to use auto-sizing I could not seem to find a good one.

Comment: Probably has more info than you need, but it is a well written tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can read up Ray's [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display). It shows exactly how to do this. You will need to click the sideways `I`/ the `H` at the bottom and click either: `Leading Space to Superview` or `Trailing Space to: Superview`. Or at the right side of your image, you need to delete the `Leading Space...` or the `Trailing Space...` click the little cog drop down menu and delete one and test it, make sure you are in the small 3.5 inch view then test it.